# Drop and Create Addin for SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I'm trying to create Addin for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I want to use existing "DROP and CREATE To" to create a new SQL script with some modifications. My modified script have to be called thru context menu.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this or how to call this script with my Addin?

Comment: What are you actually asking for help with here? Do you need help with the script? Or do you need help with executing a script from a context menu in an addin?

Comment: I need help with executing a script from a context menu with addin.

Comment: is this with an existing or a database you want to create?  if you're looking for context menus to do this, why are you not doing it form the object explorer?  or why not just code it, which is much cleaner, quicker and in my opinion easier

Comment: @SimonPrice the OP is creating a custom SSMS addin and wants to execute a script from this new addin.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from [this website](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/MA/Writing+an+add-in), which contains resources and examples for writing an SSMS add-in.

If it doesn't contain the precise answer you need, there is a link to [a GoogleGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ssms-addins/) where the question can be asked.